# Setting SKScene as SCNPlane content crashes - Xcode 9 beta 5

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to set a SKScene as content in an SCNPlane inside an ARSCNView. Right now the SKScene is a very simple one defined in an .sks file which consists only of a red background and a green rectangle in the center. Right here's the code: first function creates an ARAnchor ahead the camera when user taps the screen, and the other one creates the SCNNode for the anchor.

When I set the plane's firstMaterial content as the skScene, I get a crash: **validateDepthStencilState:3671: failed assertion `MTLDepthStencilDescriptor uses frontFaceStencil but MTLRenderPassDescriptor has a nil stencilAttachment texture'**

This only happens running the app from XCode with the device attached. If I unplug it and run the app directly from the device I see the content correctly and I can add plenty of those ugly planes (screenshot at the bottom)

```swift
@objc func addAnchor() {
    if let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame {

        var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
        translation.columns.3.z = -1.0
        let transform = simd_mul(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)

        // Add a new anchor to the session
        let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: transform)
        sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
    }
}

// Override to create and configure nodes for anchors added to the view's session.
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {

    guard let skScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MyScene") else {
        print("Could not load skscene!")
        return nil
    }

    let sceneSize = skScene.size
    print("Scene size in points: \(sceneSize)")

    skScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
    //skScene.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    let plane = SCNPlane(width: sceneSize.width * 0.001, height: sceneSize.height * 0.001)

    plane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = skScene //Crash here

    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)

    return planeNode

}
```

[image: App working unattached to xcode]

Comment: Sounds like you have a good [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) in the making...

Comment: Thanks! I've reported it. If and when I get replied I'll post it

Comment: As a workaround, you can turn off Metal API Validation in "Edit scheme – Options" for this nasty crash to go away, keeping ability to use Xcode debugging.

Comment: I bumped the same thing. What a waste of time!

Comment: same thing any fix to this?